# How to add jump-to functionality using laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I want to implement a *jump to* functionality. It is basically like a breadcrums but not exactly. It is a `dropdown` and can have left and right button. Please see my code below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <a href="previousItemIfHas" class="btn btn-default">←</a>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Jump to
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Assignment1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Quiz2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Quiz4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Assignment2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <a href="nextItemIfHas" class="btn btn-default">→</a>
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Controller**

```
$course = Course::with([
   'assignments' => $undeleted,
   'quizzes' => $undeleted,
   'add_links' => $undeleted
])->findOrFail($course_id);
$course_items = collect($course->assignments);
$course_items = $course_items->merge(collect($course->quizzes));
$course_items = $course_items->merge(collect($course->add_links));
$course_items = $course_items->sortBy('item_number');
```

**Result want:**
If the `$course` loops, it can list the items sort by `item_number`. If you are click the first item, then there should be **no** `left arrow`, same with the last item, if you click the last item, there should be **no** `right arrow`. The list of items are listed in the `dropdown` I've created.

**Problem**
I don't have any idea how can I add a condition if the `item` is the first item so I can remove the left button, and same with the last item.

*Note:* I'm using laravel 5.1

Comment: so what's the behaviour of the arrow buttons? Are they links to the previous and next pages? Also, are the dropdown items themselves links too? If they are links, are you re rendering the markup server-side (Blade) or handling the transition in the front-end?

Comment: Something like this: http://introjs.com/ ?

Comment: @alepeino Yes they are links, the `left arrow` is a previous item in the collection and the `right arrow` is the next item. Yes the dropdown items are links too. I've already listed the items, but I can't figure out the logic for the `left and right` buttons

Comment: @ThomasMoors Sort of, but please have a look at my mark up above.

Comment: @Hash - Look into [paginators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination).

Comment: @fubar Paginator is different from this.

Comment: Could you post your template code?

Comment: @Rick What do you mean template code?

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean in the template:

you can use

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
  <p>This is user {{ $user->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

inside the "foreach" loop you has the variable loop

```
@foreach ($users as $user)

@if ($user == reset($users )) 
    This is the first iteration.
@endif

@if ($user == end($users))
    This is the last iteration.
@endif

<p>This is user {{ $user->id }}</p>

@endforeach
```

so you can see if first or last item

more:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm using Laravel5.1

Comment: then use `@if ($item == reset($items )) First Item: @endif`

Comment: Can you edit your answer? and then link the `reset()` of laravel?

Comment: Why are you using user? instead of my actual data needed? Take a look at my controller.

Comment: Please be nice.

Answer (score 0):

### Hello Try this

it will start with no prev button, when you click on any thing has prev, prev will be shown, also when you click on anything has no nex the next will be hidden.. and so on..

give id="next" to next and id="prev" to prev buttons

#### Please run this snippet

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <a href="previousItemIfHas" class="btn btn-default" id="prev">←</a>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Jump to
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Assignment1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Quiz2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Quiz4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Assignment2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <a href="nextItemIfHas" class="btn btn-default" id="next">→</a>
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$('#prev').hide();
$(".dropdown-menu li").click(function(){
      if($(this).next('li').length <= 0) {
      $('#next').hide();
      } else {
          $('#next').show();
      }

      if($(this).prev('li').length <= 0) {
           $('#prev').hide();
      } else {
           $('#prev').show();
      }
    
   });
</script>
```

Comment: This is great, but if I visit the link the result is different, I mean If you click the prev button *(if you are in the first item)* then the page redirects to that page and then, the prev button is still there.

Comment: Hello @Hash, I didnt get it :(, can you please explain it more..?

Comment: I apologize with the confusion. I mean, I tried your answer, but when I click the `prev` button, so it will redirect me in the first item on the `list (e.g. assignment, quiz etc.)` page, but then the prev button is still there which must be removed because I am in the first page or first item in the list,

Comment: The list `(e.g. assignment, quiz etc.)` has their link, each item there has own link

Comment: did you try the snippet ?

Comment: ah but when you select from the list its ok ?

Comment: Yes I did. This jump-to widget/functionality will be applied on every page that is in the list (e.g. assignments, quizzes, etc.)

Comment: It is the same even if I click from the list.

Comment: I know that your snippet is working, if you have only one page and not going anywhere, but if you have different page and applied it, it won't work, because maybe the event that we used? because we need to click first before it work